# Prevent printing of full URL path

Tags: css, print

When printing on any page, I have an issue where the FULL path of the link is printed under the link name, my logo is also not printing and things are overlapping. All in all, the print is very messy and I'm not really sure where to look. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.[image: Print Issue]

Comment: Is this a custom theme or a third-party one?

Comment: it is a custom theme @DanHanly

Comment: Can you update with the code that prints a link out.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not exactly sure where to look because this is the way that it prints when i simply select File>Print directly from the browser. @DanHanly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, now I understand what you mean when you say print. Actually printing out of a printer!
I had thought it was displaying this way when you print to screen.

Your issue isn't a Magento one, but is a CSS one.

Standard CSS for Printing usually prints the URL out afterwards; this is a fairly common occurrence.

Look for something like this in your css file:

```
@media print{
   a:after{
       content:" (" attr(href) ") ";
   }
}
```

And remove it!
Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That was exactly what i was looking for!! I should have said said printing to printer lol, sorry about that.